# Hover and focus in browser inspection

Tags: html, css

I want to know if there is the possibility, by browser inspection of write a new class containing new hover/focus. For example

```css
.CanIDo {
/*something css
(ex.)*/
 width: 100;
}

/*my question (BY BROWSER ISPECTOR, i don't want to type it directly in my css using a text editor)*/

.CanIdo a:hover{
opacity: 0.7;
}
```

I think this is impossible because browser ispector don't admit to change a class directly, but only the containing of that class (right?), but maybe there are browser that have impove that, I think it can be helpful developing a web site.

Thanks!

Comment: You can directly edit the HTML in inspect mode and it would immediately reflect that in the browser

Comment: Yes. You can do anything you can do with html and css files. NOTE: instead of a plain class, when using a pseudo class like something:hover, change the plain one to 'something:link'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are asking if you can write CSS "on the fly" in a browser Dev Tool and see the effects immediately on your page?

The short answer is yes. The Dev Tools in Chrome, FireFox, and even the latest IE/Edge browsers have that ability. You can tweak applied styles one by one using a DOM inspector or even wholesale update a CSS file in a Sources tab (the name varies slightly between browsers).

And yes, you can write pseudo-class rules like hover and they'll take effect. You can develop or tweak your code and see the results immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have inspect tools that allow you to add any class on the fly.

For instance on Chrome if you open Developer Tools you can add any class to your css, be that a  `:hover` variant or any other normal class, pseudo-class.

What you have to do is open the inspector `Cmd + Shift + I` on OSx and you'll see this on the **Elements** tab:

[image: Inspector screenshot]

You can see that on the Filter you have a "+" button, clicking that you'd be able to stuff like this:

[image]

Those two classes a:hvoer and other-class are added via the inspector as you can see on the right is written: `inspector-stylesheet`